# how can I use subquery in CASE THEN?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

I tried to use subquery in CASE THEN like below.(I wrote down the code in ORACLE)

```
WITH SAMPLE AS (

SELECT 1 AS VALUE_, 
       '20191230' AS DATE_
FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT 2 AS VALUE_, 
       '20201230' AS DATE_
FROM DUAL)

SELECT VALUE_,
       DATE_,
       CASE
           WHEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE, -12), 'YYYYMMDD') IN (SELECT DATE_ FROM SAMPLE)
                THEN (SELECT VALUE_ FROM SAMPLE WHERE DATE_ = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE, -12), 
                     'YYYYMMDD'))
           ELSE NULL
       END AS ONE_YEAR_AGO_VALUE_
FROM SAMPLE;
```

I expected to get a new column(ONE_YEAR_AGO_VALUE_) that has NULL in first row and 1 in second row.

However, result was different then I expected.

The result had a 'ONE_YEAR_AGO_VALUE_' that had NULL in first row and NULL in second row.

I want to make second row have 1.

If you let me know the wrong thing in my code, I really appreciate that.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code does not make sense in many ways.  For instance, you are treating `DATE_` as a date, when it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I fix your query to have correct use of dates, then it produces one row with `NULL` and one with `1`:

```
WITH SAMPLE AS (
      SELECT 1 AS VALUE_, DATE '2019-12-30' AS DATE_
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS VALUE_, DATE '2020-12-30' AS DATE_
      FROM DUAL
     ) 
SELECT S.VALUE_, S.DATE_,
       (CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS(S.DATE_, -12) IN (SELECT S2.DATE_ FROM SAMPLE S2)
             THEN (SELECT S2.VALUE_ FROM SAMPLE S2 WHERE S2.DATE_ = ADD_MONTHS(S.DATE_, -12))
       END) AS ONE_YEAR_AGO_VALUE_
FROM SAMPLE S;
```

Your code is also overly complicated.  You don't need a `CASE` expression, which you can use directly for the value.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=715b609d33e02b7744df305adcf0e232) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I didn't  consider the simple code that you gave. Thank you. And I have another question. In subquery, does the code 'WHERE S2.DATE_ = ADD_MONTHS(S.DATE_ , -12)' make that subquery as 'correlated subquery'? I learned that if two columns that are from different tables are compared in WHERE, it makes the subquery as correlated subquery. Is it right?

Comment: @WooseokChoi . . . In general, you should qualify *all* column references in a query.  This is especially true in correlated subqueries.